# connect / ssh as root using a script without everytime typing the password

Tags: server, scripts, ssh, password, remote-access

Is there any way to connect or ssh using a script without everytime entering the password from my machine. 
I tried
 `ssh key-gen` available  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520030/script-that-ssh-to-remote-host-enters-pass-and-executes-a-command) , it is working but when I want to run something as root user or admin user again I need to enter the password, whereas its of no use for me.

Please let me know if there is any other way for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you need to run script with `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

On your target server add `username ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` as a final line to `/etc/sudoers` file.

This will allow you to run `sudo` comands from the name of your user without inputing password.